# How to display the value results of Ember find App.Model.find() in console?

Tags: ember.js

Whenever I enter `App.Model.find()` in the Chrome console I have to do a series of steps to see the actual values:

Class --> _ember###_meta: Meta --> values --> content

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `toArray()` on a collection is a handy way to do that.

Ember Data 0.13

```
console.log( App.Model.find().toArray() );
```

Ember Data 1.0.beta.1

```
console.log( this.store.find('model').toArray() );
```